# Adding Signature to PDF using VBA Macro's

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe

I am having some issues adding my signature into the Adobe PDF. For some reason, I can't add my digital ID into the PDF using the additional code.

I keep on getting a Run-Time Error '13': Type Mismatch

Any suggestions?

I got the macro working so that it adds in the Signature field using the following code -

```
Sub Prepare_PDF()

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim pdfPDDoc As New AcroPDDoc, oJS As Object, oFields, oAttachment As Object

Dim strFName As String

Dim strSignature As String

Dim strSignFName As String

Dim oParam As Parameter

strFName = "70145173 - 0100771347.pdf"


'------- Add signature fields to PDF file----------

If pdfPDDoc.Open(strFName) Then

Set oJS = pdfPDDoc.GetJSObject

Set oFields = oJS.AddField("SignatureField1", "signature", 0, Array(200, 620, 450, 670))


'------- Save PDF file------------------

strFName = Left(strFName, Len(strFName) - 4) & "-signed.pdf"

pdfPDDoc.Save 1, strFName

End If

Exit_Proc:

    Exit Sub
       

Err_Handler:

    MsgBox "In test" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & "--" & Err.Description

    Resume Exit_Proc

End Sub
```

Now when I add this code in to get my digital ID added, it error's out.

```
Sub Prepare_PDF()

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim pdfPDDoc As New AcroPDDoc, oJS As Object, oFields, oAttachment As Object

Dim strFName As String

Dim strSignature As String

Dim oPpklite As Object

Dim strSignFName As String

Dim oParam As Parameter

strFName = "A:\PDF File\Cost Transfer - 70145173 - 0100771347.pdf"

strSignature = "C:\Users\Desktop\FirstName.pfx"


'------- Add signature fields to PDF file----------

If pdfPDDoc.Open(strFName) Then

Set oJS = pdfPDDoc.GetJSObject

Set oFields = oJS.AddField("SignatureField1", "signature", 0, Array(200, 620, 450, 670))

Set oSign = oJS.GetField("SignatureField1")

Set oPpklite = oJS.security.getHandler("Adobe.PPKLite", True)
      oPpklite.login "{'Password', '" & strSignature & "'}"
      oSign.signatureSign oPpklite
      oPpklite.logout

'------- Save PDF file------------------

strFName = Left(strFName, Len(strFName) - 4) & "-signed.pdf"

pdfPDDoc.Save 1, strFName

End If

Exit_Proc:

    Exit Sub
       

Err_Handler:

    MsgBox "In test" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & "--" & Err.Description

    Resume Exit_Proc

End Sub
```

Comment: "errors out" is not a very useful description of exactly what's happening when you run your code.  Comment out the error handler and see where it halts, and tell us the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me: i do the signing in two steps. (i did it in Access, but it should be almost the same for Excel)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'the position of the signing box on the PDF
Const Y = 524
Const X = 14
Const W = 106
Const H = 59

Public Function PreparePDF(InputPDF As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim pdfPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

Dim OutputPdf As String: OutputPdf = "C:\fact\Temp.pdf"
'it needs to be an array
Dim sg_arr() As Variant: sg_arr = Array(X, Y + H, X + W, Y)

Dim oJS As Object
Dim oPpklite As Object
Dim SignField As Object

Dim HadError As Boolean: HadError = False

Set pdfPDDoc = New AcroPDDoc

If pdfPDDoc.Open(InputPDF) Then
    Set oJS = pdfPDDoc.GetJSObject
    Set oPpklite = oJS.security.getHandler("Adobe.PPKLite")

'add the signature field to the PDF, then save and close. Otherwise, 
'Acrobat will give the following message: 
'"GeneralError: Operation failed. Field.signatureSign:0: This operation cannot be done before the document has finished downloading. Please try again later."

Set SignField = oJS.AddField("Sgn", "signature", 0, sg_arr)
    
    pdfPDDoc.Save 1, OutputPdf
    
End If
    
    
Exit_Proc:
If Not oPpklite Is Nothing Then oPpklite.logout

Set oJS = Nothing
Set oPpklite = Nothing

Set pdfPDDoc = Nothing

If Not HadError Then
    If SignPDF(InputPDF) Then
        MsgBox "Successfully signed " & InputPDF & "!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        
        Dim Fso As New FileSystemObject
        Fso.DeleteFile "C:\fact\Temp.pdf", True
        Set Fso = Nothing
        
        PreparePDF = True
    Else
        PreparePDF = False
    End If
Else
    PreparePDF = False
End If

Exit Function
            
Err_Handler:
    HadError = True
    Debug.Print "In SignPDF" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & "--" & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Proc
        
End Function

Public Function SignPDF(OutputPdf As String) As Boolean '(inputpdf As String, outputpdf As String)
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim InputPDF As String: InputPDF = "C:\fact\temp.pdf"
    Dim strSignFName As String: strSignFName = "C:\fact\PFA.pfx"
    Dim pass  As String: pass = "******"
    
    Dim pdfApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
    Dim pdfPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
    
    Dim oJS As Object
    Dim oSign As Object
    Dim oPpklite As Object
    Dim ResultLogin As Boolean
    Dim ResultSign As Boolean
    Dim arr() As String
    
    Set pdfApp = New AcroApp
    Set pdfPDDoc = New AcroPDDoc
    
    If pdfPDDoc.Open(InputPDF) Then
        Set oJS = pdfPDDoc.GetJSObject
        
        Set oPpklite = oJS.security.getHandler("Adobe.PPKLite")
               
        ResultLogin = oPpklite.login(pass, "C:\fact\PFA.pfx")
        
        oPpklite.setPasswordTimeout pass, 200
        
        Set oSign = oJS.GetField("Sgn")
        
        arr = VBA.Split("", ",")
    
        ResultSign = oSign.signatureSign(oPpklite, arr, OutputPdf)
        
    End If
    
    SignPDF = True
    
Exit_Proc:
    If Not oPpklite Is Nothing Then oPpklite.logout

    If Not pdfApp Is Nothing Then
        pdfApp.CloseAllDocs
        pdfApp.Hide
        pdfApp.Exit
    End If
    
    Set oJS = Nothing
    Set oSign = Nothing
    Set oPpklite = Nothing
    
    Set pdfPDDoc = Nothing
    Set pdfApp = Nothing
    
    Exit Function
            
Err_Handler:
    SignPDF = False
    Debug.Print "In SignPDF" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & "--" & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Proc
        
End Function
```

And to call it:
PreparePDF "pdf_file_to_be_signed.pdf"

Obviously you need to reference acrobat.tlb